# How to create NSString with a specific ending

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

there. I have an iOS app, where user receive ratings from server. This is a simple city guide, and each landmark has its ratings. So the idea is to give each landmark a special id to simplify the rating system. 
That's the code in .h fie

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *placeId;
```

in .m file

```
@synthesize placeId;

placeId = @"art1";

NSString *jsonUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someurl.cfapps.io/rating/%@",placeId]; <--does notwork
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

that's what log says `someurl.cfapps.io/rating/(null)`

The question is how to open string with a specific ending (specific id) Thank You!

Comment: use `[placeId retain]` It will work....

Comment: @FahimParkar pardon me, but what do You mean, set property to retain or what? Please code

Comment: I believe you are passing placeId from another view controller... right? If yes, just use `/%@", [placeId retain]`

Comment: no, that's a property in present view. I am passing some other data. That how it works : if (someData = @"123") placeId = @"art1"

Comment: check my answer.. I have posted alternative to this answer...

Comment: Your problem is that `placeId` is nil.  Odds are this is because you're referencing a different instance of your class than the one where you set `placeId` (or perhaps you simply set a local variable somewhere named `placeId`).  When referencing a property in your own class you should always prefix with `self.`.  This eliminates a lot of ambiguities and will prevent many errors.

Comment: @FahimParkar - This code is almost certainly ARC, and `retain` will produce a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Something is not right.

Get rid of the @synthesize (no longer needed in the most recent version of Objective-C) and always use dot notation to reference your property (`self.placeID`). Make sure your property is declared as strong (better yet nonatomic, strong.)

The fact that your code compiles with the "strong" qualifier on your property tells me that you are using ARC, not manual reference counting.

Try this test:

Header:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *placeId;
```

.m file:

```
self.placeId = @"art1";
NSLog(@"placeId = %@", self.placeID);
NSString *jsonUrlString;
jsonUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someurl.cfapps.io/rating/%@",
  self.placeId];
NSLog(@"jsonUrlString = %@", jsonUrlString);
```

Post back what you get from your log statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
NSString *jsonUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someurl.cfapps.io/rating/%@",placeId];
```

Comment: If placeId is integer, he would rather use %d.

Comment: And how to declare this id? in .m file I did placeId = @"art1"; but that does not seems to be working

Comment: placeId = @"art03";

NSString *jsonUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someurl.cfapps.io/rating/%@",placeId];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: If you print jsonUrlString to the console, what do you get?

Comment: So placeId is null, this is your problem now.  Try:
self.placeId = @"art03"; 
NSString *jsonUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"someurl.cfapps.io/rating/%@",self.placeId];

Comment: @AviTsadok Nope, same (null) at the end